# how to reset a random generated number each button clicked

Tags: javascript

[The code is creating a two random generated password, every click the random password should also reset, please help.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y58ll.png)

```
const characters = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "~", "`", "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "_", "-", "+", "=", "{", "[", "}", "]", ",", "|", ":", ";", "<", ">", ".", "?",
    "/"];

let generateButton = document.querySelector("#generateButton")
let randomPassOne = document.querySelector("#randomPassOne")
let randomPassTwo = document.querySelector("#randomPassTwo")

generateButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        let randomOne = Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length)
        let randomTwo = Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length)
        passOne = characters[randomOne]
        passtwo = characters[randomTwo]
        randomPassOne.textContent += passOne
        randomPassTwo.textContent += passtwo
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a local variable then set the text content after your loop.

```
const characters = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "~", "`", "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "_", "-", "+", "=", "{", "[", "}", "]", ",", "|", ":", ";", "<", ">", ".", "?",
    "/"];

let generateButton = document.querySelector("#generateButton")
let randomPassOne = document.querySelector("#randomPassOne")
let randomPassTwo = document.querySelector("#randomPassTwo")

generateButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    let passOne = '';
    let passTwo = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        let randomOne = Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length)
        let randomTwo = Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length)
        passOne += characters[randomOne] // append your random char
        passtwo += characters[randomTwo] // append your random char
    }
    // replace existing textContent with your new passwords
    randomPassOne.textContent = passOne;
    randomPassTwo.textContent = passtwo;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the changes recommended by [user3252327](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3252327/user3252327).

That should improve the code, but since your code updates the .textContent on every iteration of the loop, it seems that may not be the issue?

It's possible that the 'textContent' value is **not** actually the value which is being displayed in your browser. This is common in buttons and other types where the text you see rendered is instead on an attribute within the HTML element. This attribute is often called 'value', but it could go by other names instead. So see if there are other attributes on your #randomPassOne HTML element that might be holding the text.

Or...

The query is not functioning properly.

I would recommend opening your dev tools in the browser (In chrome this is Ctrl+Shift+i on Windows, or CMD+Shift+i on Mac) and try running in the console `console.log(document.querySelect("#randomPassOne"))` and verify that your query can find the element in the DOM.

If that does not work - your query is not finding your elements. Try another approach like document.getElementsByClass() or document.getElementById().

If that works, then try manually updating the innerText with `document.querySelect("#randomPassOne").textContent = "hello world"` in the console to ensure that that's actually the field you need to be updating. The element should automatically update to say "hello world", no refresh needed!

Good luck!

Comment: I think the issue is that he never resets randomPassOne.textContent. The first generation is ok. But subsequent click on generatePassword appends new characters to the initial passwords